# How to use webView in read mode kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I have an app and i want to open the URL with Reading Mode 
Without ads or something the reader don't need to see

How can i do that haw can i enable the reading mode on in kotlin ?

Answer (score 1):

Try it with WebView,
In .xml file add this code:

```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
           <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
```

And inside activity(or fragment)

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.webkit.WebView;

 public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }
 }
```